# Best way to architect test development in Python so that tests can be run either with a mock or without a mock?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I'm starting a fresh `python` project and I want to write unit and integration tests with mocking and stubbing. However, I would like to run these tests during the build-pipeline against actual services by spawning these dependent services in a docker container. What is the best way to architect my project so that I can easily enable and disable mocking so that:

- tests are run with mocks in local branches
- tests are run with actual services (with mocks disabled) in CI build pipeline

I'm using `python3` and `pytest` for my purposes.

Comment: Perhaps this questions makes more sense if asked in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @MauroBaraldi for the suggestion, I did that and have already received a useful response there.

Comment: Put the link of answer here 

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/44745/45222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on "Software Quality Assurance & Testing" Stack Exchange page and received an answer that works.This can be achieved by inheriting two different test classes from one abstract test class and calling one or the other depending on the environment the test is run on.

More details in this answer:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/44745/45222